# Automorphism of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})^r$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, automorphism-group

I'm stucked with this question, I have no clue. We denote $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})^r:=\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})\times\ldots\times\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ $r$ times, I have to show that if $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})^r$, then there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots,r\}$ such that $f(e_i)=e_{\sigma(i)}$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,r\}$ where $e_i=(0,\ldots,0,\underbrace{I_n}_{\text{index }i},0,\ldots,0)$. The only idea that came to my mind is that the matrices of $f(e_i)$ are projections, thus their trace is equal to their rank, I believe one can show that all except one are of rank $0$ with this reasoning... Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal M_n$, then $f:\mathcal M_n \to \mathcal M_n$.  However, you are making a statement about $f(e_i)$, where $e_i \in \mathcal M_n \times \cdots \mathcal M_n$.  Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put the $r$, $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})^r$.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying.  Also, what kind of automorphism is $f$? Is $f$ an automorphism of rings?

Comment: $f$ is an automorphism of algebra.

Comment: I think everything is clear now.  Do you have a previous result that might be useful here?  Perhaps a classification of the automorphisms of $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$?

Comment: The goal is to find all the automorphisms of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, a classification of these is thus not allowed, there is no previous result, only the case n=1 has been done.

Comment: Are these unital homomorphisms? That is, does it necessarily hold that $f(I,\dots,I) = (I,\dots,I)$?

Comment: Yes they are indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $S = \{e_1,\dots,e_r\}$ can be characterized as the set of elements $M$ of $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)^r$ that satisfy the following:

- $M$ has rank $n$,
- $M$ is in the center of $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$ (i.e. $MX = XM$ for all $X \in \mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)^r$),
- $M$ is a projection (i.e. $M^2 = M$).

Because $f$ is an automorphism, it must preserve the above properties.  Thus, $f(S) \subset S$.  Because $f$ is invertible, $f|_S : S \to S$ must be a an invertible map, which means that there exists a permutation $\sigma$ for which $f(e_i) = e_{\sigma_i}$, as was desired.

---

Proof that $f$ preserves rank:

Note that for $M \in \mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$, the set
$$
S_M = \{MX : X \in \mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)\}
$$
is a linear subspace of $\mathcal M_{n}(\Bbb C)^r$ that satisfies $\dim(S_M) = \operatorname{rank}(M)\cdot n$.  Note that $f(S_M) = S_{f(M)}$, which means that $\dim S_M = \dim S_{f(M)}$, which means that $\operatorname{rank}(M) = \operatorname{rank}(f(M))$.

Comment: The next step is to show that when $f$ is $\Bbb{C}$-linear then $f(e_i) = A e_{\sigma_i} A^{-1}$ for some $A\in M_n(\Bbb{C})$

Comment: Thank you ! I don't understand why $f$ keeps the rank, if you could detail this point...

Comment: @Tuvasbien actually now that I think about it again I'm not quite sure how to show that this holds. It would also be enough to show that $f$ keeps the trace, but this I'm also stuck with.  It is easy enough to show that $f$ has these properties if it is an automorphism of $\mathcal M_{rn}(\Bbb C)$

Comment: @Tuvasbien I made the proof work after all; see my latest edit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you define the rank of an element of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})^r$, how did you find $\dim(S_M)=rank(M)\cdot n$ ?, if $rank(M)\geqslant (n+1)/(n-1)$ you would have $\dim(S_M)>n+r=\dim\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})^r$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien Sorry for not explaining. We identify the element $(A_1,\dots,A_r) \in \mathcal M_n(\Bbb C^r)$ with the $(nr) \times (nr)$ block-diagonal matrix
$$
\pmatrix{A_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && A_r}.
$$
The rank of $M$ is the rank of the corresponding map on $\Bbb C^{mr}$.

Comment: Ok I see, I thought it was the rank of the matrix $(A_1,\ldots,A_r)\in\mathcal{M}_{n,rn}(\mathbb{C})$.